# Permissions to edit an attachment in a list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I want people to be able to edit an attachment in a List item, but NOT be able to delete or add an attachment.  Thus, I set up the below customized permission (I have SP 2013 Enterprise), but individuals are able to add a document with the below Customized permission.  What is wrong ?  Note within the list I turned off inherited permissions and give unique permissions.

**List Permissions** (Below is what I checked)
Edit Items
View Items
Open Items
View Versions
Create Alerts
View Application Pages

**Site Permissions**
Browse Directories
Use Self Service Site Creation
View Pages
Browse User Information
Use Remote Interfaces
Use Client Integration Features
Open
Edit Personal User Information

**Personal Permissions**
Manage Personal Views
Add/Remove Personal Web Parts
Update Personal Web Parts

Comment: This is possible if the person opens the attachment using Edge.

Answer (score 1):

Attachments are part of the list item, you have given users with **Edit items permission**, its nothing but making changes to the items. Internally editing the items means making changes to the content DB, so the same permission is needed to create an item and delete an item, that's the reason why the users are able to add and delete items from that list.

I don't think that SharePoint gives permission level to only edit the attachments in a list item.

Comment: But according to the Permissions Levels Page Edit Items is the following:  Edit Items in lists, edit documents in document libraries.  Within this permission page (my customized permission) I do NOT have checked off Delete Items and Add Items.  The users with this customized permission can NOT add or delete a list item and they can not add an attachment from within the List item.  However, but for some reason once they open an attachment they can do a Save As and save with a different name essentially then being able to add an attachment.  Please explain...thx